# Grouping fields together

Tags: drupal, drupal-fields

In Drupal, is it possible to make use of multiple fields for a single option? For example, if a dropdown menu with a label of "What time do you wake up?" lets the user select a day of the week (Mon-Sun), beside it would be an empty textfield where they can type in the time.

Comment: Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 ? Also why not to use a single "selection" type field?

Comment: This has to be moved to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need both fields to be combined into one field in the database, then I believe it's just a matter of styling the particular content type in your template so that the two fields appear side-by-side instead of one on top of the other.

Comment: Allow me to clarify: the 2nd field can't be used if the first one has no value. Also, I'm looking at making the field unlimited. This means generating the first field multiple times and the 2nd field shows up for every new field generated. Is this even possible?

Comment: @enhance: when you create/edit the field, there should be a field setting called _Number of Values_, which is the _Maximum number of values users can enter for this field. 'Unlimited' will provide an 'Add more' button so the users can add as many values as they like._

Comment: Yes, but that refers only to a specific widget. What I'm after is that fields are generated like they were siamese twins—attached to one another. By default, fields are generated singularly and not in groups. Is it possible to do it in groups?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CCK and there you have a module "Content Multigroup" You can use this.